# UnicodeDecodeError adding model in Django

Tags: python, django, unicode, decode

When trying to add a model containing unicode in Django 1.9, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /cleaner/clean/add/
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 209: invalid start byte
```

This occurs in the model class.

```
class Clean(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cv = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank = True, null = True)
    cvfile = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file_extension])

    #override save method
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_text = self.cvfile.read()
        self.cv = get_text
        self.cv=self.cv.decode("utf-8")
        super(Clean, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I thought `self.cv.decode("utf-8")` would solve this as I'm using python 3.6.4, but it does not.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Did you try setting the encoding attribute on the FileField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/file/  It's your read method that is failing to decode on the FileField not the TextField.

Comment: If you mean cvfile = models.FileField(encoding ="utf-8"), I have. It gives a TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: what version of django you are running. Is it compatible with python 3? Do you need to use python3 ?

Comment: Django 1.9 and yes I'll need python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. For anyone that might have this problem in the future:

To fix this, change the line: `self.cv=self.cv.decode("utf-8")`

to: `get_text = self.cvfile.read().decode("utf-8", 'ignore')`